# Eliminar información de las variables de una estructura de datos

Tags: c++

tengo una tarea donde se deben registrar los datos de 5 productos. A través de un menú de opciones, el usuario debe ser capaz de agregar, mostrar y eliminar los datos. Mi problema recae en el apartado de eliminar los datos de un producto en particular, esto se debe hacer a partir del numero del producto.

Digamos, por ejemplo, que quiero eliminar los datos del producto numero 1. Por lo que a través del numero del producto, se deben de eliminar sus datos y dejarlos en blanco.

Así es como tengo la estructura de los datos:

```
struct producto {
char nombre[50]; //Nombre del producto
char descrip[500]; //Descripción del producto
int precio; //Precio del producto
int cant; //Cantidad
} producto[5];
```

Y esto es lo que intente hacer para eliminar los datos:

```
int main () {
    int num;
    int borrar;
    int n = 5;

    //Si el usuario elije la opción de eliminar

    cout << "\nIngrese el numero de orden que desea eliminar: ";
    cin >> num;

    if (num > n) {
        cout << "ORDEN INEXISTENTE";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "\nEl producto" << i << "es: ";
            cout << producto[i].nombre;
            cout << producto[i].descrip;
            cout << producto[i].precio;
            cout << producto[i].cant;
        }
        cout << "\nEl elemento eliminado es: " << borrar;
    }
    else {
        borrar = producto[num].nombre; //Error
        borrar = producto[num].descrip; //Error
        borrar = producto[num].cant;
        borrar = producto[num].precio;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == num) {
                while (i < n) {
                    producto[i].nombre = producto[i + 1].nombre;
                    producto[i].descrip = producto[i + 1].descrip;
                    producto[i].cant = producto[i + 1].cant;
                    producto[i].precio = producto[i + 1].precio;
                    i++;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        n = n - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << "\nEl producto" << i << "es: ";
            cout << producto[i].nombre;
            cout << producto[i].descrip;
            cout << producto[i].precio;
            cout << producto[i].cant;
        }
        cout << "\nEl producto eliminado es: " << borrar;
    }
}
```

Otro problema que presente al hacer esto, fue que tenia un error que me decía que no podía asignar un dato de tipo char a un valor de tipo int. Por lo que no puedo eliminar los datos de tipo char (el nombre y la descripcion). Otro error que tengo es que sin importar el numero de producto, solo se eliminan el del ultimo producto

Cabe mencionar que no puedo usar punteros pues no los he visto en clase.
Apreciaría mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido/a Jade! Te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (si lo haces todo ganarás tu primera medalla). Te recomiendo que edites tu problema y seas más especifico/a a la hora de describir tu problema. ¿Qué problema enfrentas para eliminar los datos? Pueden ser muchísimas cosas. Además sería bueno que agregues el código de lo que has intentado para este método de eliminar una entrada... Esto para poder tener un contexto del obstáculo que enfrentas.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias. Ahorita soy mas especifica

Comment: El error es bastante descriptivo cuando haces `borrar = producto[num].nombre;` estás tratando de asignar `nombre` que es un array de caracteres a una variable de tipo número entero. Además ¿Porqué haces todas esas asignaciones a la variable `borrar` si al final siempre tendrá el valor de `borrar = producto[num].precio;` que es la última asignación?

Comment: De hecho, ahora que lo pienso, ni si quiera usas la variable `borrar`, solo la reasignas 4 veces y no la usas luego en tu código.

Comment: Es que así lo había visto en un tutorial, solo que en vez de borrar los datos de una estructura era de un arreglo/vector. Debido a que lo encontraba sobre estructura de datos tenían cosas que no había visto en clases, pensé que podía ver como se hacia para un arreglo y utilizar la misma lógica

Comment: Mil disculpas, acabo de notar ese error sobre la variable borrar. Al agregarla donde faltaba, hace cero los valores de tipo int pero del ultimo producto, a pesar de no ser el producto que seleccione

Comment: ¿Porqué en vez de utilizar esa variable, simplemente no utilizas el índice del elemento que quieres borrar y reasignas sus elementos a los valores que representen a un elemento vacio?

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo hacer eso ultimo?

Comment: Accede al objeto que vas a borrar por medio de su índice en el array y edita sus variables internas.

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia, podria mandarme un ejemplo, por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Digamos, por ejemplo, que quiero eliminar los datos del producto numero 1

Tienes dos opciones:

**Limpias el registro**

Esta opción consiste en dejar el registro sin datos

```
producto[num].descrip = '\0';
producto[num].cant = '\0';
producto[num].precio = 0;
producto[num].cant = 0;
```

Esta opción tiene como desventaja que los registros vacíos ya no se quedan al final de la vista, sino entre medias de registros válidos. Es decir, al recorrer la vista para visualizar datos tendrás que filtrar los campos vacíos. De la misma manera para añadir registros nuevos tendrás que ir buscando los huecos.

**Eliminas el registro**

Esta opción consiste en *subir* los registros que siguen al que vas a borrar. De esta forma eliminas los datos del registro y dejas un hueco al final de la lista

```
for (int i=num+1; i<5; i++)
{
    producto[i-1] = producto[i];
}
```

Nota que ahora los dos últimos registros tendrán los mismos valores, necesitas una variable que te indique cuántos registros tienen valores válidos.

Esta opción tiene como ventaja principal que los huecos quedan al final de la lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta! Me sirvió mucho

Answer (score 0):

> Digamos, por ejemplo, que quiero eliminar los datos del producto numero 1. Por lo que a través del numero del producto, se deben de eliminar sus datos y dejarlos en blanco.

Puedes igualar la estructura a conjunto vacío, esto dejaría todos sus datos en blanco:

```
producto[num] = {};
```

> Otro problema que presente al hacer esto, fue que tenia un error que me decía que no podía asignar un dato de tipo char a un valor de tipo int.

Efectivamente no puedes igualar datos de tipo diferente (a no ser que sean convertibles entre si), observa tu estructura:

```
struct producto {
    char nombre[50];
//  ^^^^ <--- nombre es char[50]
    char descrip[500];
//  ^^^^ <--- descrip es char[500]
    int precio;
//  ^^^ <--- precio es int
    int cant;
//  ^^^ <--- cant es int
};
```

Por eso obtienes esos errores:

```
    int borrar;
//  ^^^ <--- borrar es int

...

        borrar = producto[num].nombre; //Error
//      ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^ <--- borrar es int pero nombre es char[50]
        borrar = producto[num].descrip; //Error
//      ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^^ <--- borrar es int pero descrip es char[500]
        borrar = producto[num].cant;
//      ^^^^^^                 ^^^^ <--- Borrar es int y cant es int, correcto!
        borrar = producto[num].precio;
//      ^^^^^^                 ^^^^^^ <--- Borrar es int y precio es int, correcto!
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta! Me fue de gran ayuda